# Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'int *' with an rvalue of type 'int (*)[20]'

Tags: c++

### Main.cpp

```
#include "SelectionSort.h"

using namespace std;


int main() {

    SelectionSort<int> sorterInt;

    int test_array[20];
    sorterInt.stuffNum(&test_array, 20, 1, 200);
}
```

### SelectionSort.h

```
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class SelectionSort {
public:
    void stuffNum(T *object, int size, int min, int max)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {


            (*object)[i] = 5;


        }
    }
```

Comment: What error/warning you are getting?

Comment: `&test_array` ditch the `&`.

Comment: In my defense it's 3 AM here and I am too tired. But thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SelectionSort<int> sorterInt;

int test_array[20];
sorterInt.stuffNum(&test_array, 20, 1, 200);
```

your template have type int so your method take a int * as argument.
And you write **&test_array** who has type **int *[20]** because you send the **address** of your array.

So just remove the &

```
sorterInt.stuffNum(test_array, 20, 1, 200);
```

You need a better understanding of pointer.

edit: (read comment)

```
(*object)[i] = 5;
```

here you should remove * and () like this

```
object[i] = 5;
```

more doc here [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Comment: You missed one. `(*object)` will deref the pointer making `[i]` impossible. Should be `object[i]`.

Comment: It's not `int*[20]`, there's a missing pair of parenthesis in your answer.

Comment: and his case I agree. But if he use his template with type T of int *. He could compile.

Comment: Wait, I think I see where you are going with that, but you're getting further off the mark of what OP's goal is likely to be. They want to sort `int`, not `int *`

Comment: You should mention the fact that an array decay to and bla bla bla, that is probably what confused the OP.

Comment: That ideone link's code will blow up in your face, Stargateur. You allocate storage for the array of pointers, but none for what they point to, then dereference the pointers to uninitialized pointers and attempt dereference those uninitialized pointers and assign to the unallocated storage at them.